# Почему ошибка при добавлении элемента?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

Контроллер:

```
static DataContext connection = DbConnection.Data();
    Repository<Project> projects = new Repository<Project>(connection);
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(projects.GetAll());
    }

    public IActionResult CreateProject()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateProject(Project project)
    {
        projects.Insert(project);
        connection.SubmitChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Вьюшка:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="CreateProject">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ShortName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ShortName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ShortName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Модель:

```
[Table(Name = "Project")]
public class Project : IEntity
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    List<Task> TaskList { get; set; }
}
```

репозиторий

```
protected Table<T> DataTable;
    public Repository(DataContext context)
    {
        DataTable = context.GetTable<T>();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DataTable.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        DataTable.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DataTable;
    }

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DataTable.Single(e => e.Id.Equals(id));
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SearchFor(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DataTable.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

текст ошибки `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Project' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что в вашей базе данных ключевое поле автогенерируется, а вы явно передаете его в базу и она не знает что с этим делать. Другими словами вы либо должны отключить механизм `Identity` (это то что предлагается в сообщении) либо не передавайте это поле.

Если вы используете [`EntityFramework`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations) попробуйте добавьте аттрибут `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` для вашего `ID` поля:

```
[Table(Name = "Project")]
public class Project : IEntity
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    List<Task> TaskList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, ef  не использую, а использую ado net

Comment: @Kioshilol Пишите, разберемся, в Иллинойсе ещё не вечер   А что такое `IEntity`? Я не помню такого в Ado.NET... но я давно на темной стороне 

Comment: Это интерфейс в котором роле id и только классы которые реализуют этот интерфейс могут использоваться для создания репозитория)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблема следующим путем)
добавил `[Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]` к столбцу id

Comment: Это же атрибут Entity Framework. А вы в этой и других темах пишете, что работаете с чистым ADO.NET. Однако, внутри у вас на самом деле контекст EF. Странный дизайн.